# Change name qualities in JW Player with using smil file

Tags: video-streaming, jwplayer, smil

I've a smil file to use with jw player 6.

```
<smil>
<head>
  <meta base="rtmp://host/app" />
</head>
<body>
  <switch>
    <video src="stream1" system-bitrate="1800" width="1280" height="540" />
    <video src="stream2" system-bitrate="390" width="320" height="320" />
  </switch>
</body>
```

This is how it looks on player

[image: This is how it looks on player]

How can I show High/Med/Low instead of 540p/320p in JW player? I tried adding name, title and label parameters in video node of smil file but didnt work.

Any suggesion?

Thanks

Comment: I believe we pull these in automatically and they can't be changed I'm afraid.

Comment: Can I expect this feature in future updates, it would give more options. for example I could list locations of streams (East coast, west coast, europe, etc)

Comment: Yes, I believe we are planning on adding this in the future.

Comment: It looks like this may have been added, but I'm not clear as to in which version (it is not yet working for me):  http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/ticket/1738

Answer (score 0):

Use the title attribute. This displays "High Quality Video":

```
<video src="stream1" system-bitrate="1800" width="1280" height="540" title="High Quality Video" />
```

Comment: which version of JW Player supports it?